# CodeKit - any way to ignore js?

Tags: javascript, validation, codekit

**TLDR:** CodeKit validates my crappy dev js, and alerts when it inevitably finds an error. Can I turn this off until I'm ready to polish in production?

---

This might technically be a question for superuser, but since it has explicit code and site layout implications, I thought it might be better suited here.

Been using CodeKit to compile my LESS sheets and compress my site images. CodeKit is insisting on validating the js it finds too - I'm still in development, so it inevitably finds an error and alerts on every single damn save. This is desired when I'm in production, but that's still a few weeks away. Is there any way to prevent js validation temporarily? Somehow toggle js validation? I tried turning off all the minifiers and uglifyers, but it still runs some base set of minifications.

I'd rather consider changing the environment structure as a last resort. All my site's media is contained in a `/ui/` directory:

```
ui [watched]
-css
-images
-js
-less [compile to ../css]
```

In order to merely avoid watching `/ui/js/`, I would have to make these changes:

```
ui
-css [watched]
--less [compile to ../]
-images [watched]
-js
```

I'd have to watch two folders separately, change the site structure, and alter the compilation path - IMHO, this defeats the elegance of CodeKit, especially since I'd have to undo it when I reach prod.

Comment: You should polish your code in dev too.

Comment: Just ditch CodeKit and use a text editor like a boss.

Comment: @MaxArt CodeKit's not an IDE, boss.

Comment: Lol @MaxArt. That's my usual - my teammate started this project on LESS so there's no going back.

Comment: @SLaks I do optimize in dev, but my practices aren't nearly as strict as JSLint's standards. I find it's faster to market if I rip out code then go back and standardize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it to not be compiled automatically:

[image]

or you can stop it from bringing CodeKit to the front on error:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Does that panel set globally, or is that a file-by-file basis?

Comment: The first option will set it for just the file you select in the central pane. The latter option will do it globally.